# Xamarin Forms: Breakpoints not working when debuging shared project in iOS devices

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

No breakpoints in the xamarin forms shared project work anymore. they used to work before probably some update from xamarin has made it dysfunctional.

Tried clean/rebuilding many times, restarting machines, deleting all the build artifacts and temporary files from VS solution and also in Mac Build Server still no luck. Have anyone any idea what the cause might be?

Comment: I was getting this for a minute after I updated. If you are using the simulator try on a real device and if you are having the issue on a real device, try it on the simulator (the issue only showed up for me on one or the other, can't remember which one). It eventually went away, was not sure how. Did you try deleting the app from the device and restarting the device? Make sure you update Xamarin on your Windows machine and your Mac.

Comment: could be nice to know the reason for the downvotes!

Comment: @hvaughan3 I tried it, it works on simulator fine. tried deleting the app and restarting the device no luck. xamarin is up to date on both machines as well.

Comment: @hvaughan3 actually restarting the iphone fixed it!!!!!!!!!!!!!

post it as an answer and I will mark it as answer.

Comment: Nice! Glad it helped. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting from the comment, a good device restart fixes almost everything ;)